# (C++) I seem to be having trouble running my for loop more than once. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: c++

I have posted the question and my code below. I am basically trying to run this for loop 3 times to print the first 2 characters of the words. I've already spent an hour on this question. I need to know how to fix it.

**Question:**
Write a C++ program to create a new string using 3 copies of the first 2 characters of a given string. If the length of the given string is less than 2 use the whole string.

Sample Input:
"abc"
"Python"
"J"

Sample Output:
ababab
PyPyPy
JJJ

**Code:**

```
            #include <iostream>
            #include <string>
            #include <vector>
            #include <cmath>
            #include <ctype.h>
            #include <algorithm>

            using namespace std;

            string test(string s1)
            {
                int x = s1.length();
                string y;

                if (x >= 2)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
                    {
                        y = s1.substr(0, 2);
                        return y;
                    }
    
    
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++i)
                    {
                        y = s1;
                        return y;
                    }
    
                }

            }

            int main()
            {
                cout << test("abc") << endl;
                cout << test("Python") << endl;
                cout << test("J") << endl;

                return 0;
            }
```

Comment: Here's a tip. If you want a loop to run three times don't put a return **inside** the loop. A return exits the function (and therefore stops the loop) immediately. Use the loop to gather the results you want and then return that result **after** the loop has finished.

Comment: Also you will have to **concatenate**
 strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string test(const std::string& input) {
    if (input.length() <= 2) {
        return input + input + input;
    } else {
        std::string tmp(6, '0');
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            tmp[i*2 + 0] = input[0];
            tmp[i*2 + 1] = input[1];
        }
        return tmp;
    }
}

int main()
{
  std::string name;
  std::cout << test("abc") << "!\n";
  std::cout << test("Python") << "!\n";
  std::cout << test("J") << "\n";
}
```

You can see it running at [this link](http://cpp.sh/2bl35).

Comment: No problem so far in your effort. But it is recommended to add some description about the solution in the answer to make it clearer for the future readers. If doable, then add some comments in the code to make it even beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to fix the first loop

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
  {
       y += s1.substr(0, 2); // append two more characters to what we've got so far
  }
  return y;
```

There are other ways to do this but that's the minimal change from the code you had and hopefully illustrates the mistake you were making.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your program posted here cannot be compiled due to some small mistakes like this:

```html
for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++i) 
{ 
  y=s1; 
  return y; 
}
```

obviously the "++i" should be replaced by "++j":

```html
for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) 
{ 
  y=s1; 
  return y; 
}
```

Also,your program has some logical mistakes in it. Remember that once a function returns, it cannot be restored again. So here you cannot use a loop to "return 3 times", which is definitely wrong.

You can just complete a string in the function and then print it to the screen, that will easily solve your problem. Here is my correction of your program:

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string test(string s1)
{
    int x = s1.length();
    string y;

    if (x >= 2)
    {
        string res=s1.substr(0,2);
        y=res+res+res;
        //Given that the number 3 is very small, repeat it manually may bring a higher efficiency(though it cannot be seen exactly)
        return y;
    }
    else
    {
        return s1+s1+s1;
    }

}

int main()
{
    //I do not think this program need so many "#include", just include what we need, that is convenient
    //for readers to understand your program quickly :)
    cout << test("abc") << endl;
    cout << test("Python") << endl;
    cout << test("J") << endl;
    /*Also, I recommend that you can always test some programs with a dynamic input, so that you can find some 
    small mistakes more easily. Below is a simple example:
    cout<<"Please input a string:";
    string str;
    cin>>str;
    cout<<test(str)<<endl;*/
    return 0;
}
```

Hope my answer can help with your problem :)